# Fast Data Pulling in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

Is there any way to pull the data from Source to Destination faster ? I have two servers. One for source and other for destination. These two servers are at different countries. Not my region. I created a package to pull data from source to destination. There are more than 2 lakhs of data. If I connect with servers in my region, data pulling works fast. But when at different regions, its bit slow to pull data and insert to destination. Its taking around 6 hours to complete the pulling process of 2 lakhs data. Is there any other solution to make data transfer faster ?

Comment: lakhs are a bit too localised...(equal to one hundred thousand)

Comment: without knowing the network speed noone can help you

Comment: ok....basically is it because of network speed or machine slow or low memory or memory load ?? This is what i understood !!!!!

Comment: "Is there any other solution to make data transfer faster ?" - Fedex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some better throughput (given that your network isn't working at max speed already) if you split the Data flow tasks in two and parallelize them.

If you now get double the speed you split again to three, four, or more flows going at the same time, until your network is saturated. You have then reached the limit of how fast you can fetch data.

However, you -might- also load data faster if you export it and compress it on remote sites, then move the data to your local site, then unpack and load this.